# Reveal.js showing horizontal line over image

Tags: reveal.js

I am building a presentation with Reveal.js and I need to show a slide that is just an image. Right now Reveal.js is drawing a horizontal line across a large part of the image. I cannot figure out how to just display an image.

The code:

```
---

<section data-background-image="images/new_orleans.jpg">

---
```

What I am getting:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Reveal.js is adding a

---

to the final slide of my presentation. I am using Markdown so I am guessing it is misunderstanding the final `---` and interpreting it as me asking for an `<hr>`. I simply added a blank slide to the end and the problem went away.